# How to dismiss navigation bars on iphone iOS8 Mobile Safari when using tap drag and swipe gesture over the entire webpage

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, safari, ios8

I work on a fullscreen iphone web application using gestures like tap, drag and swipes over the entire webpage. Minimal-ui was the best solution found for this kind of project.

[According to Apple Specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/):

> The minimal-ui viewport property is no longer supported in iOS 8.

What is the new way to simulate the old minimal-ui behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on telling iOS that a webpage is webapp-compatible so users can save it to their home screens and use it as if it were a separate app, with absolutely no safari controls visible.

From the [apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

> A web application is designed to look and behave in a way similar to a native application—for example, it is scaled to fit the entire screen on iOS. You can tailor your web application for Safari on iOS even further, by making it appear like a native application when the user adds it to the Home screen. You do this by using settings for iOS that are ignored by other platforms.

...

> On iOS, as part of optimizing your web application, have it use the standalone mode to look more like a native application. When you use this standalone mode, Safari is not used to display the web content—specifically, there is no browser URL text field at the top of the screen or button bar at the bottom of the screen. Only a status bar appears at the top of the screen.

...

> Your web application can link to other built-in iOS apps by creating a link with a special URL. Available functionality includes calling a phone number, sending an SMS or iMessage, and opening a YouTube video in its native app if it is installed.

This would enable you to completely hide the safari navigation AND link to other built-in functionality such as placing a phone call or composing an SMS.